# Proving Integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to prove that
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\tan x} \ dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\cot x} \ dx$$
I have no idea what I'm gonna do first. I just checked the graph, and the result is the value of those $2$ integrals are same.
Is there any trick to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an identity 
(as stated by Rhys )

> King Property

$\int^b_af(x)dx = \int^b_af(a+b-x)dx$

So, $\int^{\pi/2}_0\sqrt{\tan x}dx =\int^{\pi/2}_0\sqrt{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+0-x)}dx  =\int^{\pi/2}_0\sqrt{\cot x}dx  $

As $\tan(\pi/2-x) = \cot x$

Comment: That identity is called the King Property, if interested

Comment: Thanks @RhysHughes I'll add it

Comment: To show this, substitute $x=a+b-t$.

Comment: @RhysHughes This is interesting. Do you know the origin of this name? I have used it thousand times but thought it was just a simple trick

Answer (score 1):

Hint: we have that
$$\cot(\pi/2-x)=\tan(x)$$